# How do I call function with changing name properly in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

So, this is my current problem:

I have locations.js file that has several functions inside with different town/area names and they all include few switches. This is example:

```
let Locations = {

town1: function (eventType) {

    switch (eventType) {
        case "load":
            // Stuff related to main starting point of this location 
            break;

    }}
```

They have been all nice for everything else, but now I'm trying to create a "main access" when starting the program. Let's call main file as manager.js

```
    let Manager = {

    setStart: function () {

       currentLocation = user.currentLoc;

       // Call load function based on current location to start program from right spot
       Locations.currentLocation("load");

}
```

Result:

TypeError: Locations is not a function

As you see, I want to call function with user.currentLoc information (town names), which are saved to database. But it seems like I cant add it to variable and just use it. What am I missing here? Do I type it wrong when calling a function? I'm quite sure that there's some easy solution to this, but even after several hours I still fail to do this right.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `Locations.town1("load")`? Also, I'm not sure that wrapping these functions in Objects is warranted in your use case. You may be better off just declaring functions within a module.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to access to a property field of the `Locations` object. This field is a function, however, if you are trying to call this function by the name of a variable, the Javascript interpreter will take it as a direct call of the function.

```
let manager = {
    setStart: () => {
        const currentLocation = user.currentLoc;

        // Access the Locations property
        const fn = Locations[currentLocation];
        // Invoke the function
        fn(`load`);
    }
};
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps `Locations[currentLocation]('load')` is what you mean to call, but all the same - it looks like Locations isn't in scope in your Manager file, you need to import it somehow. That could be a missing `require` or `import` depending on your project

Answer (score 0):

```
let manager = {
setStart: () => {
    const currentLocation = user.currentLoc;

    // Access the Locations property
    const fn = Locations[currentLocation];
    // Invoke the function
    fn(`load`);
}
```

};

This did it! Thanks VRoxa. I had no idea that Javascript works like this.